# Declarative Jenkinsfile Pullrequest

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

i have a Jenkinsfile in my repository. On Jenkins i setted up a Multibranch Pipeline Project for the repository. Everything is fine, it builds via Jenkinsfile for everey branch i create and triggers also on push etc. Now i want to also build at pull requests. So the pull request is triggering the build. The Problem is now that my checkout is not working for the pull request.

```
$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '${BRANCH_NAME}']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions:
    [
        [
            $class: 'CloneOption', 
                depth: 0, 
                noTags: false, 
                reference: '', 
                shallow: true
        ], 
        [
            $class: 'SubmoduleOption', 
                disableSubmodules: false, 
                parentCredentials: false, 
                recursiveSubmodules: true, 
                reference: '', 
                trackingSubmodules: false
        ],
        [
           $class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'
        ]
    ], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: 
    [
        [                                                         
            credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            url: 'my.git'
        ]
    ]
```

So now i have the problem that the branch name is PR-[number] when i create a pull request. So checking out that branch is not possible, because it not exists. I also tried it with

```
branches: [[name: '**']],
```

But then nothing builds.

What can i do to get also pullrequests Building?